# How to change SQL Server start up parameters using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to change the SQL Server startup parameters using `SMO.wmi.Service` class.

My code is working fine on SQL Server 2014 by using SDK DLL. But when I run the same code with same SDK assemblies on a machine which has SQL Server 2012, then I am getting an error that "WMI is not available this machine".

It looks like the SDK DLLs are not backward compatible, especially for `smo.wmi`.
Please help any other way to change the start up parameters programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like we can configure the service startup parameters using registry settings. Below mention article on MSDN nicely explain this process..

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190737.aspx][1]